# Пунктуационное оформление конструкции "Сразу видно..."

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

Какие знаки препинания должны стоять после конструкции "Сразу видно" в предложении "Сразу видно -(:) умный человек"
Мне кажется, что мы можем воспользоваться здесь правилом о знаках препинания в бессоюзных сложных предложениях, а именно: если между частями предложения можно вставить союз "что", то ставится двоеточие.
Прав ли я?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом  предложении лучше поставить тире:  ***Сразу видно – умный человек.***

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение с **изъяснительными отношениями**. Действительно,  в этом случае основным знаком считается двоеточие, но оно может заменяться тире. Дело в том, что это  **нераспространенное** предложение, где сложно сделать предупредительную паузу,  которая соответствует двоеточию. Розенталь называет это интонационным предупреждением.

Розенталь:  п.7. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта:  Они знали — будет буря; Отстань, не видишь — я занят.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Также можно посмотреть **примеры из Нацкорпуса**  по адресу https://ruscorpora.ru/new/search-main.html

Мы увидим, что тире  для фразы «сразу видно» применяется в большинстве случаев. Кстати, **запятая тоже не исключается**, достаточно немного изменить предложение: ***Сразу видно,  человек он умный.*** Тогда «сразу видно» можно приравнять к вводному слову (оно произносится фактически без паузы).

Примеры:

Только взял боец трехрядку,  **сразу видно** – гармонист (А. Твардовский, Василий Теркин).

Выходит член правления, и по лицу его **сразу видно** ― отказали. [Владимир Войнович (1976)]

Нет, эта бабочка безусловно настоящая ― **сразу видно**. [Валерий Медведев. Баранкин,  будь человеком! (1957)]

**Сразу видно**, человек искусства, богема, так сказать. [Юрий Медведев, 1977]

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь большое!